# Translation of "Your name means in Spanish «The new land»"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What should I use

> Dein Name heißt auf/im Spanisch(em) "das neue Land".

or

> Dein Name bedeutet auf/im Spanisch(em) "das neue Land".

Which one above is the most common form?

- First confusion for me: using "heißen" or "bedeuten"
- The second one is: "auf" or "im"

Comment: Ich könnte mir vorstellen, daß dieser Satz überflüssig ist. Zumindest wenn ich Terranova hieße, wüßte ich schon, was das bedeutet.

Answer (score 4):

The correct usage would be

> Dein Name bedeutet im Spanischen: *Das neue Land*

*heißen* ist mostly used when you assign a name to something, e.g.

> Mein Hund heißt *Hector*

*bedeuten* is used when a name or word has a special meaning, is being translated or is being explained, e.g.

> *resignieren* bedeutet aufgeben
>   
> *(to) translate* bedeutet übersetzen

Comment: Someone please just verify my thought here before I incorporate it into the answer: *auf Spanisch* --> Akkusativ / *im Spanischen* --> Dativ?

Comment: I think it is impossible to tell, which case it is in "auf" because I don't think there is an example in which you would have a word that would carry a marker. But just based in feeling, I'd say it is Dative too... I don't feel like there is any directional aspect at all.

Comment: Aber auch die in der Frage enthaltene Variante mit Anführungszeichen statt Doppelpunkt ist möglich, oder? *Dein Name bedeutet im Spanischen »das neue Land«.*

Answer (score 0):

*Heißen* means *to be called*

> Ich heiße José - I am called José

and *bedeuten* means *to mean*

> Hund bedeutet *dog* auf Englisch.

And the correct way to say it is:

> Dein Name bedeutet im Spanischen: Das neue Land

Comment: Hmmm... "Hund heißt auf englisch dog" would be quite as valid. There is some overlap between "heißen" and "bedeuten".